# Booting 2 Emergency Mode: Failed to Mount /Var

Tags: centos, filesystems, mount, virtual-machine, data-recovery

CentOS7 booting into emergency mode.  Here are the errors found in `journalctl -xb`

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed

sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through

gspca_vc032x: reg_r err -32

bcma: bus0: No SPROM available

EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem

Failed to mount /borg

Failed to mount /var
```

I see /var in fstab so /var does have a mount point

```
/dev/nvmeVg/var     /var            ext4    defaults        0 0
```

Just prior I had reduced the size of `nvmeVg-var` so I could increase the size of `nvmeVg-home` which I successfully did.  I then resized the filesystem and expected a normal reboot but went to emergency mode.  Commands were

```
lvreduce -L44G /dev/mapper/nvmeVq-var

lvextend -L181G /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home

resize2fs /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home
```

│ ├─nvmeVg-var  254:0    0    44G  0 lvm
│ └─nvmeVg-home 254:1    0   181G  0 lvm

I ran `sudo e2fsck -C0 /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var` and got `/dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var is in use`

I also tried

```
[root@localhost-live DataCabinet]# e2fsck -C0 -f /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var
    e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
    The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 32768000 blocks
    The physical size of the device is 11534336 blocks
    Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
    Abort<y>? no
    Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
    Error reading block 11534368 (Invalid argument) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
    Force rewrite<y>? yes
    Error reading block 11534369 (Invalid argument) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
    Force rewrite<y>? yes
    Error reading block 11534370 (Invalid argument) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? no
    Error while scanning inodes (2759055): Can't read next inode                   
    Error writing block 11534368 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error<y>? yes
    Error writing block 11534369 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error<y>? yes
    e2fsck: aborted
```

***I have located backups of*** `/var/www` now next steps do I resize the filesystem or try to repair the filesystem before restoring? The later makes sense to me.

```
[root@localhost-live snapshots]# fdisk -l /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var
Disk /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var: 44 GiB, 47244640256 bytes, 92274688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

[root@localhost-live snapshots]# fdisk /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The device contains 'ext4' signature and it will be removed by a write command. See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x26e63ccd.
```

Comment: Exactly what did you do to reduce `nvmeVg-var`? If you just did a `lvreduce -L <new size> nvmeVg-var`, you just cut off the tail end of the `/var` filesystem. You would need to either use the `-r`/`--resizefs` option to try and shrink the filesystem together with the LV, or first resize the filesystem before resizing the LV, taking care to shrink the filesystem *as much or slightly more* than you're going to shrink the LV, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: lvreduce -L44G /dev/mapper/nvmeVq-var is what cut the tail off.

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed did not do a `resize2fs /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var 44G` or equivalent before running `lvreduce -L44G /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var`, then you've definitely damaged your filesystem by cutting off its tail.

And since you have already extended the other filesystem, rolling back to the previous configuration using `lvmcfgrestore` and the standard backups in `/etc/lvm/backup` might not be a good option either, since it would most likely break your `/home` in the same way.

Restoring your `/var` from a recent backup would be a great solution here. But I assume you don't have that, do you?

You might have to run `e2fsck -C0 -f /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var` and accept a big scary error message about the filesystem having a larger size than the underlying device. Then it will hopefully finish up the tail amputation process you inadvertently performed, and set the filesystem size to the value matching the current size of the LV.

Comment: I did cut off its tail.  First time doing this.  My bad.  I have backups.  right now I am running "sudo fsck /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var" it's been force rewriting for house now.

Comment: "sudo fsck /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var" has been going for hours now.  Is this normal?